# Integer to array of chunks

Tags: ruby, range

I need to turn an integer into an array of intervals. For example,

```
number_to_steps(number: 10, step: 3)
# => [[0, 2], [3, 5], [6, 8], [9, 9]]

number_to_steps(number: 7, step: 2)
# => [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 6]]

number_to_steps(number: 8, step: 2)
# => [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

I tried:

```
def number_to_ranges(number:, size:)
    chunks = ((number - 1) / size.to_f).ceil

    (0..chunks - 1).map do |index|
      from = index * size
      to = (index + 1) * size - 1

      [ from, to > number ? number : to ]
    end
  end
```

But it doesn't work properly. For example,

```
number_to_ranges(number: 14, step: 4)
[[0, 3], [4, 7], [8, 11], [12, 14]]
```

should not go to 14.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative (to your method) would be to use [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice).

```
def number_to_steps(number:, step:)
  (0...number).each_slice(step).map { |arr| [arr.first, arr.last] }
end
```

Tests:

```
number_to_steps(number: 10, step: 3)
 #=> [[0, 2], [3, 5], [6, 8], [9, 9]]

number_to_steps(number: 7, step: 2)
 #=> [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 6]]

number_to_steps(number: 8, step: 2)
 #=> [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

Comment: I was sure there were better ways to do this than what OP was trying. I too would have preferred this way. I was more focussed on fixing the existing code only for unknown reasons. :)

Comment: `(0...number).each_slice(step).map(&:minmax)` :)

Comment: @engineersmnky very slick!

Answer (score 7):

```
def number_to_steps(number:, size:)
  (0..number-1).step(size).map { |i| [i, [i+size, number].min-1] }
end

number_to_steps(number: 10, size: 3)
  #=> [[0, 2], [3, 5], [6, 8], [9, 9]]

number_to_steps(number: 7, size: 2)
  #=> [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 6]]

number_to_steps(number: 8, size: 2)
  #=> [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

Comment: `(0..number-1)` is same as `(0...number)` :)

Comment: @JagdeepSingh, as a matter of practise I always use two dots. I believe two dots here, three dots there gives rise to bugs. (I may be in the minority.)

Comment: Or `0.step(number - 1, size).map { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

There are two places where you need to change your method `number_to_ranges`.

- When calculating the number of `chunks`, change `number - 1` to `number`.
- When finding the last element for a chunk, do `number - 1` instead of `number`.

This is what the final code should look like:

```
def number_to_ranges(number:, size:)
  chunks = (number / size.to_f).ceil

  (0...chunks).map do |index|
    from = index * size
    to = (index + 1) * size - 1

    [from, [to, number - 1].min]
  end
end

number_to_ranges(number: 10, size: 3)
 => [[0, 2], [3, 5], [6, 8], [9, 9]] 

number_to_ranges(number: 7, size: 2)
 => [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 6]] 

number_to_ranges(number: 8, size: 2)
 => [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]] 

number_to_ranges(number: 14, size: 4)
 => [[0, 3], [4, 7], [8, 11], [12, 13]]
```